# creating JSON with few columns from another JSON

Tags: json

I have a JSON file like following:

```
[{"PROV_32_ID":1.0,"Pname":"Kabul","Time":9107,"value":24.0,"Children59m":0.0},
 {"PROV_32_ID":1.0,"Pname":"Kabul","Time":9110,"value":92.0,"Children59m":8.0},
 {"PROV_32_ID":1.0,"Pname":"Kabul","Time":9111,"value":78.0,"Children59m":4.0}]
```

I would like to create another JSON with only three columns like following from the above JSON object.

```
[{"Pname":"Kabul","Time":9107,"value":24.0},
 {"Pname":"Kabul","Time":9110,"value":92.0},
 {"Pname":"Kabul","Time":9111,"value":78.0}]
```

Anybody, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the for loop

**UPDATED**

```js
var json = [{"PROV_32_ID":1.0,"Pname":"Kabul","Time":9107,"value":24.0,"Children59m":0.0},{"PROV_32_ID":1.0,"Pname":"Kabul","Time":9110,"value":92.0,"Children59m":8.0},{"PROV_32_ID":1.0,"Pname":"Kabul","Time":9111,"value":78.0,"Children59m":4.0}]

for(var i in json)
{
 delete json[i]['PROV_32_ID'];
  json[i]['value'] = json[i]['Children59m'];
  delete json[i]['Children59m']; 
}
console.log(json)
```

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful and how can I rename the Children59m to value.

Comment: you want to put the values of `Children59m` to `values`? Can you show a sample

Comment: Yes I want to rename it to value or move the value from Children59m to value. The data is demo but my actual data will not have value key.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted & upvote . Cheers